# Navigation bar color changes to match the section

Tags: javascript, css, navbar, bulma

I'm trying to design my webpage so that the navigation bar color changes to match the section that the user is reading.
For example when the user is on a red section, the nav bar should be red etc. 
Nota: I'm using bulma as a css library.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html class="has-navbar-fixed-top">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
<nav class="navbar is-fixed-top is-transparent" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
  <div class="navbar-brand is-transparent">
    <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
      <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
    </a>

    <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu is-transparent">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <a class="navbar-item">
        Home
      </a>

      <a class="navbar-item">
        Documentation
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
        <a class="navbar-link">
          More
        </a>

        <div class="navbar-dropdown">
          <a class="navbar-item">
            About
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
            Jobs
          </a>
          <a class="navbar-item">
            Contact
          </a>
          <hr class="navbar-divider">
          <a class="navbar-item">
            Report an issue
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a class="button is-primary">
            <strong>Sign up</strong>
          </a>
          <a class="button is-light">
            Log in
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<section class="hero is-primary is-fullheight">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="title">
        Green Fullheight  hero with navbar
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
  
<section class="hero is-link is-fullheight">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="title">
       Blue Fullheight hero with navbar
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</html>
```

**Edit :**

The navigation bar should be changed when the user is scrolling down or top. 
A similar behavior is used by dropbox for their homepage : 
https://www.dropbox.com/

**My solution :** 
 Consists of making the navigation bar transparent :

```
.navbar {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was the problem?

Comment: @Alouani Younes where is js. I have done this sample using bootstrap https://codepen.io/Merajkhan/pen/vroLvr

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Comment: @Pete what can't you understand in my question ? 
I made a snippet and described what I want. shahid was helpful and at least tried to answer. 
If you can't be helpful or can't understand a question don't comment. Silence is gold. I figured out the solution myself.

Comment: *and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* not a link to an external site - if you want to include the external link, make sure there is still enough code in the question that people don';t need to use the link.  I see no css in the question therefore as your question is about changing colours, not enough code ergo off topic for SO

Comment: I will delete the question in few minutes. I guess this will make you happier.

Comment: If you don't want to follow the rules of SO - try reading off topic section, then expect to be downvoted and closed voted. and yes it would make me happy if you deleted this off topic question - or edited it to follow the rules.  Have a read of this too, whilst you are refreshing yourself about the rules: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Since it's no longer possible to delete the question (Users invested time). I edited it :
- added full code 
- added a website that uses the technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually my question is clear but many people just down voted without even telling why. Hopefully I figured out the answer myself. The solution is to make the navigation bar background transparent with css only. No JavaScript needed :

```
.navbar {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add some jquery to add and remove required classes

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#blue").mouseover(function(){
    $(".navbar").addClass("is-link");  
  });
  $("#blue").mouseout(function(){
    $(".navbar").removeClass("is-link");  
  })
});
```

Here is the working demo of your code and only I'v added functionality to blue section.
[demo](https://codepen.io/shahidali/pen/pQBZGp)

Comment: This solution is not working as expected because once the mouse is in a red section but the view is on a green section, the navigation bar is red. It's not the desired behavior. 
Thank you anyway.